# Do Azure API Mgmt have a length limit on path/parameters?

Tags: rest, azure, url-parameters, azure-api-management

I have some APIs published in Azure API Management, that call a REST web application behind the scenes. Most of the endpoints use the format:

```
https://company.azure-api.net/dom/ep/{pathParamVal}?{queryParamName}={queryParamVal}
```

If `{queryParamVal}` is a really long string which causes the URL length to exceed 350-400 characters, everything works as expected. But if I specify that same string value as the `{pathParamVal}`, I get a HTTP 400 error code - `HTTP Error 400. The request URL is invalid.`. I know this is related to Azure, because the underlying web application works with lengthy path parameters as well as query parameters.

Is there a limitation on how long the URL path can be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a limitation on how long the URL path can be?

Base on my experience, the limition of the WebAPI path is  260 characters that same as the [Windows Maximum Path Length Limitation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247(VS.85).aspx#maxpath).The Maximum length of URL is limited by the different browsers. More details about the maximum length of a url in different browsers please refer to another [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers).

**Update :**

I do a test for it. If the length of `pathParamVal` >260 then will get the bad request. Or it works correctly. More detail please refer to the screenshots.

1. If the length of pathParamval >260, then it will get the 400 bad request error.

[image]

2. If the length of pathParamval =260, then it works correctly.

[image]

Comment: I am primarily concerned about the path length, because overall lengths can be much higher and still work, if the path parameter value is supplied as a query parameter.

Comment: I have updated the answer, more details please refer to it

Comment: Is this a default limit that can be increased?

Comment: Yes, it is the default limitation. unfortunately, we can't find a way to increase it currently.

Comment: Thanks for confirming.

Comment: Ran into this issue this week.  Looks like the path length maximum is now 324 (note we didn't test with a query string, but just the URL).

Comment: Ignore my last comment, can't edit it anymore.  Did some more research and came up with this:  


Ran into this issue this week.  Look like this length issue will be there when any one part of the path is longer than 261 characters.  Have a URL that accepts zips as part of a path parameter and it fails when longer than 261.