# Can I change the Azure Function app url length limitation?

Tags: c#, azure, http, url, azure-function-app-proxy

I noticed that if the URL parameter is over 260 characters I get this response:

> HTTP Error 400. The request URL is invalid.

by parameter i mean:

> http://websiteName/parameter1name/{parameter1value}/parameter2name/{parameter2value}

if one of the values lengths is more then 260 characters I get that error.
is there a way to change the function app settings to extend this limitation?

Comment: I doubt you could change that, nor should you even try. Instead, perhaps you should be POSTing the data in the body instead?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do Azure API Mgmt have a length limit on path/parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42211627/do-azure-api-mgmt-have-a-length-limit-on-path-parameters)

Comment: no errors when running Azure Func locally